# DFA that accepts strings with last character being repeated at least 1 time before

Tags: automata, finite-automata

I'm trying to design a DFA in a 4 digit language, for example L(a,b,c,d) or L(1,2,3,4) that accepts strings with the last character being already repeated before.

Everyway im trying, i get so many transitions im literally lost in them...

So, for example, abbdb is accepted (because b is showed again at least 1 time) but abc is rejected since c (last char) never shows up more than 1 time.

I managed to make it work for a language with 2 DIGIT:
For example:
[image]
Which accepts for example aa or ababa but can't do for 4 DIGIT language.

Comment: Try first when the alphabet is smaller.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yes i already have tried to do that too and i can't achieve anything. u can look at the edited post an example with 2 digits.

Comment: You can also try solving it for a general alphabet - might be easier than a special case.

Comment: i managed to achieve this for 2 digit language.. but still i want 4 digit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write out a description of this machine rather than drawing it.

- States ($Q$): the states of this machine are five-tuples $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \sigma)$: alpha, beta, gamma, and delta are in $\{0,1\}$ and record whether or not the corresponding symbol has been seen before, while sigma is in $\Sigma \cup \textrm{Nothing}$ and indicates the last symbol read.
- Alphabet ($\Sigma$): the alphabet, as you specified, is $\{a,b,c,d\}$.
- Start ($q_0$): the starting state is $(0,0,0,0,\textrm{Nothing})$. In other words, we've seen no symbols yet, and the previous symbol read was nothing.
- Final States ($F$): a state is final if the last symbol read was seen before. For example, the state $(1,\#,\#,\#,a)$ is final, regardless of what those $\#$s in the middle are.
- Transition function ($\delta$): this is the trickiest part. If we're in a state $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta, \sigma)$ and see the symbol $s$, we want to go to the state where $s$ has been seen, and where $s$ is the last symbol read. If we see $a$, for example, we go to state $(1, \beta, \gamma, \delta, a)$: we mark that $a$ has been seen, don't change $\beta$, $\gamma$, or $\delta$, and record $a$ as the most recently read symbol.

Comment: is this a description for general fsm or for a DFA because i struggle to convert this to a DFA in my mind.

Comment: @Konstantinos This is a description for a DFA that accepts your language. I wouldn't recommend drawing it out by hand because the number of states grows exponentially with the size of your alphabet, as you've probably discovered. I don't think a DFA can recognize this language in less than exponential space.

Comment: Is there a way to determine my problem how many states it will need? @Draconis

Comment: @Konstantinos In my DFA it takes $(n+1)2^n$ states; this number can be reduced somewhat by merging some of the final states, but it remains exponential in $n$.

Comment: Okay thank you actually that helps more than you think. The answer now is complete @Draconis